# I bring things down

Tags: riddle

> I bring things together, start revolutions
>
> Few truly know me or my execution
>
> Relatively speaking, I have two solutions
>
> I work not through force, but mass distribution.

Comment: Sounds a lot like physics.... not my strongest suit...

Comment: This question has generated a large number of plausible answers, which suggests that it may be under-defined.  Perhaps you could add some more lines to the riddle to further narrow down the solution.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain i will add another 8 lines later

Comment: @AricFowler Ping me when you have, and I can retract my vote to close :-)

Answer (score 18):

Trying this because that's sounds like what I'm studying right now.

First solution:

> Gravity

I bring things together, start revolutions

> Because gravity holds stuff together and is the cause of revolution of planets around the Sun

few truly know me or my execution

> Something about how General Relativity is not so widely known or understood unless you are a physicist?

relatively speaking, I have two solutions

> Probably the fact that there's Newtonian gravity and General relativity, two models of gravity? Maybe? That "relatively" makes me think that you're referring only to GR...

I work not through force, but mass distribution.

> The gravitational field is related to the energy-momentum tensor that for massive object contains information about mass distribution and the idea of a "force" of gravity is only true in Newton's theory

---

Second solution (poorly explained):

> Communism

I bring things together, start revolutions

> Not sure about the first bit, but the idea of a revolution is strong in communism

few truly know me or my execution

> Now there's only two states with a communist government (China and Cuba)

relatively speaking, I have two solutions

> --- is this only about how the riddle has two solutions?

I work not through force, but mass distribution.

> One of the ideas of communism is the mass distribution of goods among the population

Comment: almost half way

Comment: @AricFowler What does halfway mean?? He got the answer or not??

Comment: What do you mean? Two of my explanations are wrong or the answer is half wrong?

Comment: @FrodCube Possibly that there are 2 solutions and you found just one

Comment: @dcfyj exactly.

Comment: Added another solution, but I don't know too much about that subject

Comment: If you take the time, you'll find it.

Comment: I feel like a secondary answer 'fear' kinda fits.

Comment: General relativity is one of the solutions, newton's theory is not. "I work not through force, but mass distribution" shows this. Also, the second solution has yet to be guessed.

Answer (score 5):

> Ideas.

I bring things together, start revolutions

> Revolutions start with an idea and like-minded people.

few truly know me or my execution

> I can't articulate this well. Maybe that's proof?

relatively speaking, I have two solutions

> Success or failure of an idea?

I work not through force, but mass distribution.

> Ideas that garner support from the majority become the community ideal

edit: I bring things down

> Regimes or current powers toppled by new ideologies

Comment: Interesting answer - welcome to Puzzling! c:

Comment: I really like this answer, though the title of the puzzle is not answered

Comment: @Krishnabhadra added

Answer (score 3):

I think its

> Propaganda

I bring things together, start revolutions

> Propaganda has been known to start and finish wars

few truly know me or my execution

> Most people don't know what goes into the creation or execution behind the scenes

relatively speaking, I have two solutions

> This is a riddle of two parts

I work not through force, but mass distribution.

> Propaganda tries to sway the public opinion of something

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is

> Mahatma Gandhi

```
I bring things together, start revolutions
```

> He started a peaceful revolution with the goal of unity, not overthrowing a government

```
few truly know me or my execution
```

> General knowledge outside of asia about Gandhi is rather superficial; Also, he was assassinated

```
relatively speaking, I have two solutions
```

> The two ground principles of Gandhis revolution were "truth" and "non-violence"

```
I work not through force, but mass distribution.
```

> The revolution was not about forcefully taking over, but about awareness. The more people believed in the principles, the better it would work.

If it is not that, it's still probably about

> Some kind of famous executed revolutionary, I would think. All lines are very well applicable to a person.

Answer (score 1):

My take is

> Inertia

I bring things together, start revolutions

> Moment of inertia of a body helps it to rotate.

few truly know me or my execution

> Most people don't know about inertia. It's too common a concept for anyone to really pay attention.

relatively speaking, I have two solutions

> Maybe, this relates to the fact that the question has 2 answers. Not sure about this, anyway.

I work not through force, but mass distribution.

> Moment of inertia depends on distribution of mass.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the solution could be:

> Love! Yes, love of all things.

I bring things together, start revolutions

> "Peace not War!" Is a popular revolutionary tactic among citizens of countries. Love Brings people together, their hearts connect, as they fall in love ;)

few truly know me or my execution.

> It's not common knowledge how Love works at all, in fact I still don't understand it all that much, aside from the fact that it's something to do with a chemical in the brain. Nor do they know why or how they fall in love. The execution of their love.

relatively speaking, I have two solutions.

> You can learn to love the other person, Or you are already in love with them. (Honestly this is the hardest of all the steps to answer) 
>  
>  It could also be referring to Maternal/Paternal love, (Family love) Or it could mean relationship love.
>  
>  
>  It might even be that all of the above are grouped together, and the two solutions are Love for others and love for yourself. 
>  
>  
>  And if we group that with the rest under love for people, we can think of 'Love for what we do' Like our hobbies, or work, etc.

I work not through force, but mass distribution.

> Love isn't forced upon you... it's something you embrace, accept... and everyone (subjective) loves to love. Mass distribution of feel-good lovey-dovey stuff.

I feel like this is both a far stretch and a wonderful answer. It was worth a shot.(Totally not Biased >.>)

Answer (score 0):

The second possible answer could be

> Glue

I bring things together, start revolutions

> Glue is used to stick things together, I have no idea about the revolution part :(

few truly know me or my execution

> Few people know how glue is made, and what's inside. Few people really know how to use glue efficiently (how to apply it on a surface)

relatively speaking, I have two solutions

> I was always told you can use either boiling water or "Acetone" to dilute glue

I work not through force, but mass distribution.

> Glue in itself doesn't do much, it only works when applied on a surface / distributed on a mass, unlike clips for exemple

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess:

> Magnets

I bring things together, start revolutions

> These are some things that magnets do, physically.

few truly know me or my execution

> As the great poets ICP once asked, "Magnets: How the f*** do they work?!"

relatively speaking, I have two solutions

> North and South poles

I work not through force, but mass distribution.

> I'm guessing this has something do with how magnets actually work.

Answer (score 0):

My answer

> Genetics

I bring things together, start revolutions

> Genetics brings couples together and I'm sure I've heard the term genetic revolution!

few truly know me or my execution

> Genetics and the expression of genes are still a mystery

relatively speaking, I have two solutions

> The genetic mutations are either successful or they are not

I work not through force, but mass distribution.

> You can't force genetic change but, success is from a mass distribution of genetic material!

The title, I bring things down

> The cascading of genes down through the generations. Genetics bring certain traits down to the next generation!

Answer (score 0):

I will go for the second possible answer here since we all agree that the first one is:

> Gravity.

My second option is:

> Money

I bring things together, start revolutions

> There is a saying "Money makes the world go round". I would add "only if you spend it on alcohol and you drink it. Then it literary makes your world go around". Usually revolutions start because of money.

few truly know me or my execution

> Not many people understand the "man made, artificially sustained" monetary system.

relatively speaking, I have two solutions

> You can have cache or virtual money on your card.

I work not through force, but mass distribution.

> In order for money to fulfill it's purpose it has to trade hands.

Answer (score 0):

My answer for the second one is

> Anarchy.

Explanation:

I bring things together, start revolutions.

> Anarchy brings the population together and revolutions are started because of it

few truly know me or my execution

> Most people don't really know what Anarchy is and how it works

relatively speaking, I have two solutions

> Kinda of a longshot but Anarchy has two major point of views of how it is achieved. Insurrecionary Anarchy and social Anarchy. Or, you can talk about communism and socialism, two major systems that seek to become an anarchy.

I work not through force, but mass distribution.

> Although some think the contrary, Anarchy can't be achieved by force, because it needs all population, or at least, the major part to it work